# Epicor V9 to V10 conversion

Tags: c#, business-process-management, erp, epicorerp

I've got the following lines of C# code in an Epicor V9 system but can't come up with the correct conversion for Epicor V10. Any suggestions?

public static Epicor.Mfg.UI.App.QuoteEntry.TopLevelSheets topLevelSheets1;

topLevelSheets1 = (Epicor.Mfg.UI.App.QuoteEntry.TopLevelSheets)mainPanelObj;

Answer (score 0):

This is so painful. Hope this helps someone in the future.

public static Erp.UI.App.QuoteEntry.TopLevelSheets topLevelSheets1;

topLevelSheets1 = (Erp.UI.App.QuoteEntry.TopLevelSheets)mainPanelObj;

You will need to add a reference to Erp.Contracts.BO.PartPlantSearch.dll

Comment: We eventually dropper the static for all the objects in our customizations. If I remember correctly we ran into issues when a user would have two instances of Epicor open. You may not run into this issue specifically but I think when you create a new customization inside10 it hulls it out without it.